# Ubuntu is getting stuck at pruple boot screen

Tags: 14.04, boot

My Ubuntu was working all fine but suddenly it got shutdown and now it is not getting past the purple boot screen. I tried using the recovery mode but i get presented with some error logs. What could be wrong in this case? I have attached the image below.

I also tried doing `fsck` but i got that `fsck is not installed`. Unfortunately i do not backups of many important files on the system. I would like to know if there is any option of recovery.

[image: here is the image of logs]

Comment: The mounting of /dev/sda2 (root) failed, so it couldn't start init. Boot from Ubuntu -live  and repair the disk and mounting.

Comment: @abu_bua i booted from usb . how should i repair the disk ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hardware error on your disk.

Boot your computer with a Ubuntu Live system (e.g., from a USB stick) and do a `fsck` which may repair the disk and make it bootable again.